# Materialize Javascript autocomplete

Tags: javascript, formulário, materialize, autocompletar

Estou utilizando o framework materialize. De acordo com a documentação, posso utilizar "autocomplete" na tag form de acordo com o link [Materialize Form](http://archives.materializecss.com/0.100.2/forms.html). Minha duvida, é o seguinte eu quero criar um javascript para autocomplete de extensões, exemplo: @gmail.com, @outlook.com, @hotmail.com. Quando o usuario informar "@" aparecer esta lista. Abaixo meu codigo

```
  <div class="row">
            <div class="input-field col l6">
                <i class="material-icons prefix">email</i> 
                <input type="email" id="email" class="validate" autocomplete="off">
                <label data-error="E-mail invalido!" data-success="E-mail valido!" for="nome">E-mail</label>           
            </div>           
        </div>
```

Javascript:

```
     <script>
        //Função para autocomplete do email
        $(document).ready(function(){
            //pegando o id do formulario
            $('#email').autocomplete({
//Aqui declaro algumas possiveis extensoes de email para autocompletar
                data: {
                    "@hotmail.com": null, /
                    "@gmail.com": null,
                    "@outlook.com": "img/outlook.jpg",
                },
                limit: 20, // The max amount of results that can be shown at once. Default: Infinity.
                onAutocomplete: function(val) {
                    // Função quando é valido ou seja completado!
                    //alert("ok"); 
                },
                minLength: 1, // The minimum length of the input for the autocomplete to start. Default: 1.
            });
        });        
    </script>
```

Comment: E o que está dando errado no seu código?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pelo que pesquisei, o [autocomplete](https://materializecss.com/autocomplete.html) não tem ainda uma funcionalidade de mostrar as sugestões somente após determinada entrada do usuário. Vi que está na lista de upgrades do plugin.

***"Quando o usuário informar "@" aparecer esta lista."***

Se entendi o que tu precisa, segue uma alternativa...

*Obs: O funcionamento padrão do plugin foi modificado.*

```js
//Função para autocomplete do email
$(document).ready(function() {
  //pegando o id do formulario
  $('#emailAux').autocomplete({
    //Aqui declaro algumas possiveis extensoes de email para autocompletar
    data: {
      '@hotmail.com': null,
      '@gmail.com': null,
      '@outlook.com': null
    },
    limit: 20, // The max amount of results that can be shown at once. Default: Infinity.
    onAutocomplete: function(val) {
      // Função quando é valido ou seja completado!
      //alert("ok");
    },
    minLength: 1 // The minimum length of the input for the autocomplete to start. Default: 1.
  });

  detectChanges();
});

let lastLength = $('#emailAux').val().length;

$('#email').on('input', function(e) {
  let countSymbol = $(this)
    .val()
    .match(/@/g);
  if (countSymbol) {
    if (countSymbol.length == 1) {
      if ($('.autocomplete-content').is(':visible')) {
        $('#emailAux').val($('#email').val().substr($('#email').val().indexOf('@')));
        $('#emailAux').trigger(
          jQuery.Event('keyup', {
            keycode: 13
          })
        );
      } else {
        $('#emailAux').val('@');
        $('#emailAux').text('@');
        $('#emailAux').trigger(
          jQuery.Event('keyup', {
            keycode: 13
          })
        );
        $('.autocomplete-content').show();
        e.stopPropagation();
      }
      lastLength = $('#emailAux').val().length;

    } else {
      $('.autocomplete-content').hide();
    }
  } else {
    $('.autocomplete-content').hide();
  }
});

$('#email').on('blur', function(e) {
  $('#emailAux').blur();
});

let intervalID = null;

intervalManager(true, detectChanges, 1);

function intervalManager(flag, animate, time) {
  if (flag) intervalID = setInterval(animate, time);
  else clearInterval(intervalID);
}

function detectChanges() {
  if ($('#emailAux').val().length - lastLength > 1) {
    $('#email').val($('#email').val().substr(0, $('#email').val().indexOf('@')) + $('#emailAux').val());
    $('#email').focus().blur();
    intervalManager(false);
    $('#emailAux').val('');
    intervalManager(true, detectChanges, 1);
  }
}
```

```css
.autocomplete-content {
  display: none;
}

.aux {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/js/materialize.min.js"></script>

<div class="row">
  <div class="input-field col l6">
    <input type="email" id="email" class="validate" autocomplete="off">
    <input id="emailAux" class="aux" autocomplete="off">
    <label data-error="E-mail invalido!" data-success="E-mail valido!" for="nome">E-mail</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Entendi! Mas uma pergunta, como que eu começo a conta depois do @, exemplo: bruno@o (logicamente iria aparecer na lista @outlook.com). Obrigado pela ideia!

Comment: Eai @BrunoLima, editei a resposta, cara, fiz na correria o código, da pra melhorar mt coisa mas a ideia é essa... Criei um input invisível que possui o plugin autocomplete, tudo que é digitado no input visível é replicado no invisível... O resto são eventos para tratar, por exemplo, o clique em um item do autocomplete, qualquer dúvida chama ae =)

Comment: Cara muito obrigado por compartilhar sua ideia! Confesso que não sou muito bom com javascript (sou estudante ainda), Ficou perfeito! Abraços!